# ng-table with inline editable columns

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Im trying to create an ng-table which needs following

1. each cell should be editable on single click.
2. Each cell will have a template ( like few cells are text fields and few cells have options dropdown in it ).
   3.This grid should always have one empty/new row for user to enter values , as user clicks on empty/new row ( which is always shown by default ) a new row should get added.

More precise, do I have to add a template like this ?

```
 <td data-title="'Agency #'"><input type="text" ng-model="dealer.AgencyKey" /></td>
```

also for options do I have to add like this

```
<td data-title="'Account Type 2'"> <select class="form-control" ng-model="contractsHeader.AccountTypePT" required autofocus id="accountType2Options"> 
<option ng-repeat="accountType2 in accountTypes2" value="{{accountType2.KeyValue}}">{{accountType2.Description}}</option> </select> </td>
```

NOTE : I have basic knowledge on ng-table ( creating read only table by binding data from service )

Appreciate your thoughts and inputs

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? You could have a control and static text, both sharing the same model for each cell. Ng-click would toggle to the edit control on clicking a cell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , gave an idea on how to go about it

Comment: what I meant was , do I have to add a template like this ?

<td data-title="'Agency #'"><input type="text" ng-model="dealer.AgencyKey" /></td>

also for options do I have to add like this
  <td data-title="'Account Type 2'">
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="contractsHeader.AccountTypePT" required autofocus id="accountType2Options">                                                   <option ng-repeat="accountType2 in accountTypes2" value="{{accountType2.KeyValue}}">{{accountType2.Description}}</option>                                                            </select>
   </td>

Comment: This is hard to read, consider opening a new question

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your ng-repeat from the option to the select